# Hide / display row in query base on criteria

Tags: ms-access-2013

I want to hide / display row in query base on year (2014). If any color don't have year 2014, will be hide (in this case, all pink color will be hide) other wise any color have year 2014 will be display (2012,2013,2014) in query. Please help me.

### Color | Year |

RED  | 2014 |
RED  | 2013 |
RED  | 2012 |
BLUE | 2014 |
BLUE | 2013 |
BLUE | 2012 |
PINK | 2013 |
PINK | 2012 |

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
Select 
    * 
From 
    YourTable
Where 
    Color In (Select Color From YourTable As T Where T.Year = 2014)
```